# search delegate build suggestion not showing everything

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]I have a custom search delegate but the build suggestion doesn't show everything (see attach photo for reference) and giving an error that says `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range`. the code below shows the custom search delegate.

```
class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate{
  List<Product> searchterm = List.from(PRODUCTLIST);

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context){
    List<Product> matchQuery = [];
    for(var items in searchterm){
      if(items.name.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())){
        matchQuery.add(items);
      }
    }
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: matchQuery.length,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 12,
        mainAxisSpacing: 12,
        childAspectRatio: size.width  / (size.height * 0.54)
      ),
      itemBuilder: (
        (context, index) => 
        ProductSearch(
          products: matchQuery[index], 
        )
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context){
  List<Product> matchQuery = [];
    for(var items in searchterm){
      if(items.name.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())){
        matchQuery.add(items);
      }
    }
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: matchQuery.length,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 12,
        mainAxisSpacing: 12,
        childAspectRatio: size.width  / (size.height * 0.54)
      ),
      itemBuilder: (
        (context, index) => 
        ProductSearch(
          products: matchQuery[index], 
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I couldn't find what causing the error so hoping for your help.

Comment: You forgot to add the Image of your output

Comment: Is this the actual code? This errors comes up when you have passed the number to itemCount which is exceeding the actual items in list. Here it seems likes the passed itemCount is 7 and the array only contains 3 items.
Can you check your code and verify this?

Comment: @AakashKumar yes that is the actual code. actually the list contains 11 items but I only screenshot what is shown above. it contains 11 items but only shows 7 and the rest are errors

Comment: Ok. Yeah I can see now that you list have 0..6 items & its showing index of item on those error tiles. But somehow your matchingQuery is keeping all the items even after filtering them. My guess is that its actually filtering the items but putting empty objects after 7. You can test this by putting a print command just before gridview. Also I am checking the code of `buildSuggestions` only, is that the right place?

Comment: yes its in the right place.